# how to find a specific word from table using Like in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to search word in SQL server.

I am working on search bar module.

When I search women in a search bar it will show all women listing and that is correct. But when I search men It shows all listing of men and women.

I have used this below query:

```
select * from product where title like '%shirt%for%men%'
```

I want to search for word not for characters.

How can write a query to search only particular word from the tables?

Comment: Use full text search:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search.  Obviously, "men" matches "women".

Comment: add sample data & desires result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is workable in 2008 ?

Comment: Is gender its own column?

Comment: nope, I am searching for only title & description column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LIKE` operator as below :

```
 select * from product where title like '%shirt%for% men%'
```

Easy solution is to add space. You could also use regex

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing

Comment: this works, but it will start to fail if there is any other delimiter is used except for space

Comment: This could just as easily return false positives. And sql server doesn't support regex, just a very light version for sort of pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks @tylermoseley

Comment: @tylermoseley Hello, if string is "black shirt" then what i have to do.

Comment: I have used this: '% black% shirt%' & it has shown me empty record. but when I used  '%black% shirt%' then Its shows records related to black shirt

Comment: Why has this happened?

Comment: Are the entries for black shirts preceded by some text or is it the first word?

Comment: Of course, this finds "menu" and would fail to find "(men)".